# is this Point board = new Point[10] a new instance of Point?

Tags: java, instance

I have this exercise and they ask me how many instance of Point is created and they answer 14 but me I count 13 because I don't count the board as a instance. It is ? and why ? because for me we create a new board with 10 places of size of a Point but we not instance it because we need a x and a y to do no ?

```java
public class Point {
    
    private double x, y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point addition(Point p) {
        return new Point(x + p.x, y + p.y);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Point [x=" + x + " , y=" + y + "]";
    }
}

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p = new Point(1, 1);
        Point[] board = new Point[10];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            tab[i] = p.addition(new Point(i, 1));
            
        System.out.println(p);
        Point p2 = p;
        p2 = p.addition(tab[0]);
        System.out.println(p + " " + p2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please send code with sane spacing (a.k.a not `System . out . p r i n t l n`)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your logic is correct. The creation of `board` (array of `Point`) does not involve creating any `Point` instances. It is simply an array.

But there are 14 instances of `Point` created in the code:

1. Creation at line 3 (`new Point (1 ,1)`)
2. Six of them are created in the *for* loop and six more inside the `addition` method call.
3. One at line 9 (inside the `addition` method).

I think you missed the last one :)

Comment: ho yes thank you !! because I beleve than it was the same of the p.addition(tab[0]) and the first addition in the loop for but I didn't read good the code... and even it was the same addition I forgot it would have been the same value but not the same Point

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code , it is created 14 times  . I have added one  static method and static object to count no of objects. Additionally you can put debug point inside constructor and check your self , how its getting called .

```
public class Point
{

    private double x, y;
    private static int objectCount;//Counter to keep track of objects

    public  static int getObjectCount()
    {
        return objectCount;
    }
    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        objectCount++;
    }

    public Point addition(Point p)
    {
        return new Point (x + p.x, y + p.y );
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Point [x=" + x + " , y=" + y + "]";
    }
}
```

Test class is changed to print this count at various stages

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Point p = new Point(1, 1);
        System.out.println("No of Objects created after new Point(1, 1) = " + Point.getObjectCount());
        Point[] board = new Point[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            board[i] = p.addition(new Point(i, 1));
        System.out.println("No of Objects created after  for loop  = " + Point.getObjectCount());
        System.out.println(p);
        Point p2 = p;
        p2 = p.addition(board[0]);
        System.out.println("No of Objects created after  p.addition(board[0]) = " + Point.getObjectCount());
        System.out.println(p + " " + p2);
    }
}
```

O/P is

```
No of Objects created after new Point(1, 1) = 1
No of Objects created after  for loop  = 13
Point [x=1.0 , y=1.0]
No of Objects created after  p.addition(board[0]) = 14
Point [x=1.0 , y=1.0] Point [x=2.0 , y=3.0]
```

Comment: thank you !! I will think to count like this the next time ; ) , if we have more than 1 constructor we put ```objectCount++;``` in all of them ?!

Comment: Yes , you should put this in all constructors

Comment: okay thanks, at more I don't understand why p2 = Point [2.0, 3.0] and not Point[1.0, 2.0] because p2 = p = Point[1.0, 1.0] and board[0] = Point[0.0, 1.0] no ?

Comment: p2 = p.addition(board[0]); this will create new object of Point as per your definition of  addition function in Point Class . At the time of creation you are incrementing X and Y point with the argument that is passed . Put print statement in between or use IDE to debug it , this will clear your doubt . Thanks .